# Archer notification to go to a user 30 days prior to expiration date

Tags: rsa-archer-grc

I would like a notification to go out only once to a user 30 days before an expiry date is reached. If I choose Days to expiration less than 31 the notification will generate again. Could someone give me some advice. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Below are couple of approaches to meet your requirement:

1. Rule could have any valid true condition to send the Notification like "Days to Expiration" = 30 days or "Days to Expiration" < 31. Then Notification's Delivery Schedule could be created with Frequency = Reminder and Criteria as specified below:

   Days to expiration   **Equals**   30 Days   **After Today**     [Please View Criteria Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0nnw.jpg)

   (Occurrence will be auto shown as Once on forming this criteria).
2. If the notification do not have any kind of repetitive nature, then Rule could be any 'Changed to' condition with a calculated helper field which will change only once. Then Notification's Delivery Schedule could be created with Frequency = Instantly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using a Data Driven Event to generate the notification, so first thing to do is double check your 'Generate Notification' event criteria. It sounds like you're criteria says "Days to Expiration < 31" it will generate a notification. Assuming "Days to Expiration" is a calculated field, until that value recalculates to something above 31 it will send out a notification each day.

Instead what you want is one notification when it's 30 days before. You will need to change your 'Generate Notification' event criteria to say when "Days to Expiration = 30". That will send a notification when "Days to Expiration" = 30 days, and only that day.